# Is it possible to install Steam Os on an APU A4-6300?

Tags: graphics-card, steam-os

I've read about Steam OS here:

http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/buildyourown

The problem is I don't know if it will run on my future small htpc with this APU from AMD:

http://www.tiburcc.it/it-it/prodotti/AMD_X2_A4_6300_FM2_+_HD8370D;9721

I don't expect great performances because I'd just like to use little indie games.

The question is:

Will it install and run Steam even if my computer doesn't match the specs?

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know? If the installer runs, then the OS probably will, too.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but we talk about (as I said ) my future computer. So since Steam Os running on it is quite important for me it is fundamental to know from any users who tried it if it works otherwise I'll buy another cpu.